# Tableview won't fully scroll to the bottom

Tags: swift

my table view isn't allowing me to scroll all the way down im using a tableviewCell.xib to create it and I can't seem to find a fix here is the code that shows how the tableview is made

```
//MARK: VIEW LIFECYLCE
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //disable darkmode not going to be ready till later update due to time constraints
                 //==================================================
                 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                     overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
                 } else {
                     // Fallback on earlier versions
                 }
                 //==================================================





    print("the user logged in is \( String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.email))")

    tableview =  UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
           tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
           view.addSubview(tableview)


    var layoutGuide : UILayoutGuide!
    layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "dailyMotivationTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

    //MARK: TABLEVIEW CONSTRAINTS
    tableview.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DailyThoughtCELL")
   tableview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
   tableview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
   tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true



    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self



    //MARK: FUNCS
    decideUserType()
    loaddailymotivation()





}
```

and here's a picture of how it looks when it loads it won't go to the bottom of the last post[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the is because of tabBar it is hide the table view so you can add this code to your ViewController

`let adjustForTabbarInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height, 0)
self.yourTableView.contentInset = adjustForTabbarInsets
self.yourTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = adjustForTabbarInsets`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in your function

```
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you

`self.tableview.contentInset.bottom = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0`